# [React.js]No logro guardar elementos nuevos en un array

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, context

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que tiene una lista de objetivos y dentro de cada objetivo deberia poder desplegarse otra lista de subobjetivos especificos para cada objetivo principal en particular. Adjunto el componente FormSubTarea que deberia encargarse de agregar los subObjetivos y adjunto una parte del codigo donde cree el Context y en el cual esta la logica para la creacion de objetivos y subObjetivos. Tal vez la logica que elegi no es la mas adecuada ni la correcta, es mi primer trabajo en react y hace como dos dias que no puedo dar con el error. Desde ya muchas gracias
ObjetivosContext.js :

```js
  const nuevoObjetivo =(text)=>{
      const copiaObjetivo=[...objetivos];
      copiaObjetivo.push({
        text,
        check:false,
        subObjetivos:[],
      });
      salvarObjetivos(copiaObjetivo)
      console.log("inicio  array subObjetivos")
      console.log(text)
    }
      const nuevoSubObjetivo=(objetivoText, subText)=>{
        const copiaObjetivo=[...objetivos];
        const objetivoIndex = copiaObjetivo.findIndex((todo)=> todo.text === objetivoText);
        if(objetivoIndex !== -1 && copiaObjetivo[objetivoIndex].subObjetivos){
        const subObjetivo = {
          text: subText,
          check: false,
        };
        if (!copiaObjetivo[objetivoIndex].subObjetivos) {
          copiaObjetivo[objetivoIndex].subObjetivos = []; // Si el array subObjetivos no existe, se crea uno vacío
        }
        copiaObjetivo[objetivoIndex].subObjetivos.push(subObjetivo);
        salvarObjetivos(copiaObjetivo)}
        console.log("llamado a nuevosubObjetivos")
        console.log(subText)
      }
```

El formulario:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ObjetivosContext } from "../ObjetivosContext/ObjetivosContext";
import { CheckIcon } from "../Icono/CheckIcon";
import { BorrarIcon } from "../Icono/BorrarIcon";
import "../FormObejtivo/FormObjetivo.css"
// import "../CreadorSubTarea/CreadorSubTarea.css";

function FormSubTarea(){
    const {
      nuevoSubObjetivo,
      setOpenModalSubTareas,
      objetivoText,
       }=React.useContext(ObjetivosContext);
          const [nuevoObjetivoValue,setNuevoObjetivoValue]=React.useState("");
          const [objetivoIndex,setObjetivoIndex]=React.useState(null);
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    nuevoSubObjetivo(objetivoText,nuevoObjetivoValue);
    console.log("antes de llamar a submit")
    console.log(objetivoIndex)
    setOpenModalSubTareas(false);
  };
   const onCancel=()=>{setOpenModalSubTareas(false)};
   const onChange= (event)=>{setNuevoObjetivoValue(event.target.value)};
   return (
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
<label>`Agregar sub tarea`</label>
<textarea  
value={nuevoObjetivoValue}
onChange={onChange}
placeholder="Mandale mecha"/>
<div className="FormObjetivoSub-buttonContainer">
<button type="submit" className="Icono-nuevo-check"
><CheckIcon/></button>
<button type="button" onClick={onCancel} className="Icono-nuevo-borrar"><BorrarIcon/></button> 
</div>
   
</form>
  );}
 
export {FormSubTarea}
```

Comment: Quizás lo hiciste mas complicado de lo que debería ser... a ver si entiendo... tienes una lista de objetivos y estas a su vez tiene una lista de subobjetivos, deseas poder agregar tanto objetivos como subobjetivos? los quieres agregar mediante modales? es obligatorio que uses un contexto? puedo darte una versión simplificada si te interesa

Comment: Buenas, si por favor, quiero simplificar! Claro mira te cuento el primer caso practico que tendra es muy simple, una lista de unidades de una diplomatura y dentro de cada unidad las clases practicas y teoricas que la componen, solo que quiero que eso sea dinamico, con botones para poderr agregar o quitar unidades o clases segun cada persona. Y con respecto a los mdoales y el contexto pense que seria la forma mas sencilla de resolverlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un Contexto, pero en este caso no es necesario, los contextos se usan cuando tienes que pasar props muchas veces de padres a hijos (el llamado prop drilling) pero con un árbol de componentes tan pequeño no es necesario, considera que tenemos el siguiente árbol UI:

```
/* UI Tree
              Diplomaturas
              /        \
        Agregar_Dip   Diplomatura
                          /      \
              Agregar_Clase      Clase
                                                  
*/
```

**Diplomaturas.jsx** contendrá el arreglo de los nombres de las diplomaturas y la función que la modifica en un *useState* (podria ser un arreglo de objetos con otras propiedades como horarios, profesores etc pero quise simplificar), este componente enviara a **Agregar_Dip.jsx** la funcion *setdiplomaturas* para que modifique el arreglo  y el cambio se vea reflejado en **Diplomaturas.jsx**:

**Diplomaturas.jsx**:

```
import Agregar_dip from "./Agregar_dip"
import { useState } from 'react'
import Diplomatura from "./Diplomatura"

export default function Diplomaturas(){

  const [diplomaturas, setdiplomaturas] = useState(['Diplomatura en Informatica', 'Diplomatura en Quimica'])

  return (
    <div>
      <Agregar_dip setdiplomaturas={setdiplomaturas}></Agregar_dip> { /* Formulario para agregar diplomaturas */ }
      <ul> { /* lista de diplomaturas */}
        { 
        diplomaturas.map((elem, i) => 
        <li key={i}>
          <Diplomatura 
          nombre={elem}  
          setdiplomaturas={setdiplomaturas}
          id={i}>
          </Diplomatura>
        </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Agregar_Dip.jsx**:

```
import { useRef } from "react"

export default function Agregar_dip({ setdiplomaturas }) {

  const input = useRef() // reperencia al input, para poder obtener su valor

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setdiplomaturas(dips => [...dips, input.current.value]) // se agrega la nueva diplomatura
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" ref={input} required/> { /* input referido */ }
      <button type="submit">AGREGAR DIPLOMATURA</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Como ves, el componente **Diplomaturas.jsx** renderiza una `<ul>` con componentes del tipo **Diplomatura** este recibe varias props: su nombre (que recibe del arreglo) una propiedad id (que no es mas que la posicion en el arreglo) y la funcion *setdiplomaturas* (para poder eliminarse a si misma) este es su codigo:

**Diplomatura.jsx**:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Agregar_clase from './Agregar_clase'
import Clase from './Clase'
import { AiOutlineCloseCircle } from 'react-icons/ai'

export default function Diplomatura({ nombre, id, setdiplomaturas }) {
 
  const [clases, setclases] = useState([])

  const handleClick = () =>  setdiplomaturas(dips => dips.filter((dip) => dip != dips[id]))
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h4 style={{display: 'inline'}}>{nombre}</h4>
      <AiOutlineCloseCircle onClick={handleClick}></AiOutlineCloseCircle>
      <Agregar_clase setclases={setclases}></Agregar_clase>
      <ul style={{marginTop: '10px'}}>
        { 
          clases.map((elem, i) => <li key={i}><Clase nombre={elem} setclases={setclases} id={i}></Clase></li>)
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

La función *handleClick* permite mediante un icono eliminar la diplomatura, haciendo uso de la función *setdiplomatura* y id (posición) obtenidas del elemento padre.

Y ahora cada diplomatura tendrá su propia lista de clases y form para poder agregar clases nuevas, aplicamos lo mismo de antes, un **Agregar_clase.tsx** con un formulario para crear clases nuevas y un `<ul>` con varios elementos del tipo **Clase.tsx**.

**Agregar_clase.tsx**:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function Agregar_clase({ setclases }) {

  const input = useRef()

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setclases(clases => [...clases, input.current.value])
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" ref={input} required/>
      <button type="submit">Agregar Clase</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

**Clase.jsx**:

```
import { AiOutlineCloseCircle } from 'react-icons/ai'

export default function Clase({nombre, id, setclases}) {

  const handleClick = () => setclases(clases => clases.filter((clase) => clase != clases[id]))

  return (
    <div>
      { nombre }
      <AiOutlineCloseCircle onClick={handleClick} style={{marginLeft: '5px'}}></AiOutlineCloseCircle>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, solo es cuestion de renderizar el componente padre **Diplomaturas.jsx** en tu aplicacion para renderizar todo el arbol de componentes

el icono `<AiOutlineCloseCircle>` lo obtienes instalando [react icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/) escribiendo `npm i react-icons` en la terminal e importando tal y como lo escribí en los componentes que lo usan.

Espero haberme explicado bien, preguntame cualquier duda que tengas.